# AngularJS: handle click on a div with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I want to execute a JavaScript code, let's say a simple `alert()` function, if a user clicks on element with a special class within my AngularJS application. If I were to use simple jQuery, I would do it like that:

```
$('.specialClass').on('click', function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

This is exactly what I have in `main.js` file that I have included in my `index.html`. I even have several `$(document).on('click',...` pieces of code there that do actually work. However, the `$('.specialClass').on('click'...` part does not work. I have no idea how to actually implement this as elements with class `specialClass` could be encountered all over the place in different views, controllers, directives, etc. basically everywhere in the app. Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('clickable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          if ($(elem).is('div.clickable')) {
            alert('matches div.clickable');
          } else {
            alert('does NOT matche div.clickable');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.black {
  color: black;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="black clickable">clickable black div</div>
  <div class="blue not-clickable">not clickable blue</div>
  <p class="blue clickable">clickable blue p</p>
</div>
```

If you want a pure angular way of doing it, you could create a directive, which can be applied through class definition. The name of the directive would be name of the class you want to add clicks to.

*See the example above.*

**EDIT:** Answer to comment `I'm targeting is actually a query looking something like that div .specialClass and I would only care for the clicks if it's within the div`

JQuery has a function called `.is(selector)` that can be applied on elements to see if they satisfy a given selector.

So, if there is a element which is `<div class="special"></div>` doing `<elem>.is('div.special')` where `<elem>` is any div with class special, that function would return true.

Comment: Good solution but what if the class I'm targeting is actually a query looking something like that `div .specialClass` and I would only care for the clicks if it's within the div? I could, of course, add another class and use your solution, but the problem is that the app is already existing so I would have to do through all the code and add that new class...

Comment: @mmvsbg You could make use of jquery's `.is(selector)` function. See the updated answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use on for a document & add your class as a parameter
Ref : 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('click', '.specialClass', function () { 
//your code here..
    });
```

**Edit : For the DownVoters.**

This is not the angular way but will work in your case with minimal change impacts of creating those directives by finding all those elements

Comment: @HarshadHirapara yes it is not "angular" but op is already using it at a lot of places in his application.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but I did not ask for specific AngularJS solution either. I just want to handle the clicks somehow and this solution could actually be more effective in my case although it's not the angular way.